# issue with iis application www.abc.com/default.aspx/xyz

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

i am facing one issue in my asp.net 3.5 application.

www.abc.com/default.aspx - this works perfectly

when user tries to add anything after aspx after / like www.abc.com/default.aspx/xyz

my css gets disabled, and page works which i dont want.

i have used error pages but it didnt work in this . i want to disable anything user enters after url www.abc.com/default.aspx

if user enters www.abc.com/default.aspx/xyz it should display error page

how to do it ?

thankx in advance

Comment: This is something that should be handled by the ASP.NET page dispatcher (or whatever MS calls it) and is therefore a topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to StackOverflow.

but this sounds like is a simple issue that your CSS is relative (does not start with /), try change the `<link>` in the `<head>`-section to have a forward slash at first.